# How would I make chart scale proportionally with plot area in Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm making a web app with Flask, and I'm using Plotly to generate charts for a dashboard. I've set my HTML elements to be a percentage of the screen using CSS, so the web elements scale with the screen.

However, when I load the app in a different screen the the plot area scales but the chart loses it's proportion. That's because the margin has to be set to certain pixel length and won't adjust.

I tried using `fig.update_yaxes(automargin=True)` but the default margins are too wide. Is there another way in which I can automatically set the width of a margin, preferably as a percentage, e.g. 20% and have Plotly scale the margins appropriately?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.